# What is the criteria for selecting the best model in gridsearchcv with Ridge

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I have tried gridsearchcv

```
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), Ridge())
param_grid = {'ridge__alpha': [1000, 100,10,1,0.1]}
grid_pipe = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv = 5)
```

If i exclude 1000 in ridge_alpha, ridge_alpha = 100 is the best model. If I include 1000 in ridge_alpha, ridge_alpha being 1000 is the best model, however, this model has both higher rmse and lower R^2...Why does it not choose alpha = 100 even with 1000? I thought R^2 is the default criteria for regression with Ridge...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`gridsearchcv` checks every split of the cross-validation score and gets the average of all those to find the better hyperparameter. You can use `grid_pipe.cv_results_` to check every split score, average score and std score. it gives the details the result of every hyperparameter with cross-validation splits. so you can analyze that data for better understanding.

Comment: 'params': [{'ridge__alpha': 10000},
  {'ridge__alpha': 1000},
  {'ridge__alpha': 100},
  {'ridge__alpha': 10},
  {'ridge__alpha': 1},
  {'ridge__alpha': 0.1}],

Comment: 'mean_test_score': array([0.71258665, 0.85028674, 0.82807142, 0.75635483, 0.68739042,
        0.6649867 ]),
 'std_test_score': array([0.02610594, 0.04197133, 0.04905709, 0.04436738, 0.07058033,
        0.0835176 ]),
 'rank_test_score': array([4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6])}

Comment: Thank you! I guess you meant this. ridge_alpha = 1000 is the champion in the contest of cross validation using mean R^2 as criteria, and this is how gridsearchcv define as the best model. As for it loses R^2 competition to ridge_alpha being 100 on the whole training set or test set, this is just back luck. Right?

Comment: Thank you very much!